# timescaledb postgresql performance issue follow up 2

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

this question is a followed up on my previous [timescaledb postgresql performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69136283/timescaledb-postgresql-performance-issue) one where the chunking issue is resolved.

I have one issue needs help, I have a table with 67M rows like the following

```
   SELECT * FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand order by "timestamp" desc limit 1000;
```

| symbol | timestamp | volume | close | high | low | open |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ANT_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 13.198 | 5.111 | 5.123 | 5.11 | 5.123 |
| FET_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 26.443781800000004 | 0.7253 | 0.7255 | 0.7224 | 0.7246 |
| ONC_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 47.89 | 0.363 | 0.3633 | 0.3628 | 0.3633 |
| FSN_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 1044.8977859 | 0.5454 | 0.5509 | 0.5454 | 0.5499 |
| PCX_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 1158.901 | 3.926 | 3.934 | 3.913 | 3.925 |
| PRQ_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 681.83529405 | 0.6791 | 0.6807 | 0.6757 | 0.6805 |
| CREDIT_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 3045.81454624 | 0.10573 | 0.10662 | 0.10567 | 0.10567 |
| JFI_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 0.6434 | 47.08 | 47.1 | 46.91 | 46.91 |
| ENJ_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 | 2613.32204107 | 2.018 | 2.0315 | 2.018 | 2.0294 |

I have the index that I think have been properly generated

| tablename | indexname | indexdef |
| --- | --- | --- |
| db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand | db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2_symbol_timestamp_idx | CREATE INDEX db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2_symbol_timestamp_idx ON public.db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand USING btree (symbol, "timestamp" DESC) |
| db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand | db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2_timestamp_idx | CREATE INDEX db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand2_timestamp_idx ON public.db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand USING btree ("timestamp" DESC) |

One common question to query is to check what are the latest timestamp for each symbol:

```
SELECT symbol, max("timestamp") FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand group by symbol;
```

| symbol | max |
| --- | --- |
| 100X_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| 10SET_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| 1INCH3L_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:20:00 |
| 1INCH3S_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:10:00 |
| 1INCH_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| 88MPH_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| A5T_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| AAVE3L_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:55:00 |
| AAVE3S_USDT | 2021-08-31 19:30:00 |

However, this takes 15+ seconds to get me back 1000 rows…. Is this speed reasonable? Is there anyway I could make it faster? I’m on a dedicated AWS instance with 8 cores and 32GB Memory…

Here's the explain analyze result:

```
explain analyze
select symbol , max("timestamp") from public.db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand db2 group by symbol ;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Finalize GroupAggregate (cost=1102706.72..1103220.75 rows=1010 width=17) (actual time=6328.788..6385.198 rows=1028 loops=1) |
| Group Key: db2_1.symbol |
| -> Gather Merge (cost=1102706.72..1103190.45 rows=4040 width=17) (actual time=6328.770..6383.885 rows=4952 loops=1) |
| Workers Planned: 4 |
| Workers Launched: 4 |
| -> Sort (cost=1101706.66..1101709.19 rows=1010 width=17) (actual time=6286.324..6286.414 rows=990 loops=5) |
| Sort Key: db2_1.symbol |
| Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 100kB |
| Worker 0: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 100kB |
| Worker 1: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 103kB |
| Worker 2: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 103kB |
| Worker 3: Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 100kB |
| -> Partial HashAggregate (cost=1101646.16..1101656.26 rows=1010 width=17) (actual time=6284.663..6284.886 rows=990 loops=5) |
| Group Key: db2_1.symbol |
| Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 193kB |
| Worker 0: Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 193kB |
| Worker 1: Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 193kB |
| Worker 2: Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 193kB |
| Worker 3: Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 193kB |
| -> Parallel Append (cost=0.00..1017326.87 rows=16863858 width=17) (actual time=190.496..3557.402 rows=13491444 loops=5) |
| -> Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_68_2367_chunk db2_1 (cost=0.00..772558.91 rows=13957491 width=17) (actual time=63.172..1792.108 rows=11166350 loops=5) |
| -> Parallel Seq Scan on _hyper_68_2368_chunk db2_2 (cost=0.00..160448.67 rows=2906367 width=17) (actual time=212.293..858.803 rows=3875156 loops=3) |
| Planning Time: 0.230 ms |
| JIT: |
| Functions: 48 |
| Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true |
| Timing: Generation 7.376 ms, Inlining 338.267 ms, Optimization 394.122 ms, Emission 218.212 ms, Total 957.977 ms |
| Execution Time: 6387.027 ms |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of an index skip scan.  Since PostgreSQL doesn't implement them naturally, you can [emulate one](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan) with a recursive CTE.  This doesn't require timescaledb or partitioning at all (and in fact it might interfere with this--I don't know)

Or if you have somewhere a table of all symbols, you could do a lateral join against it.

```
 SELECT * FROM symbols left join lateral 
   (select "timestamp" from df where df.symbol=symbols.symbol order by "timestamp" desc limit 1) on true;
```

Comment: Great! I did something like this, ```CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand_symbols AS
select distinct symbol from db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand;
 SELECT * FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand_symbols as db2 left join lateral 
   (select "timestamp" from db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand as db3 where db2.symbol=db3.symbol order by db3."timestamp" desc limit 1) as db4 on true; ```

Comment: first query takes 10+s to build up the table of all symbols. second query just takes 0.05s. Surprisingly, even if i have index to symbol, postgre does not track distinct symbol automatically... would hashindex track distinct symbol?

Comment: indeed ```WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT min(symbol) AS symbol FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand_symbols
   UNION ALL
   SELECT (SELECT min(symbol) FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand_symbols WHERE symbol > t.symbol)
   FROM t WHERE t.symbol IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT symbol FROM t WHERE symbol IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT null WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand_symbols WHERE symbol IS NULL);
``` only takes 0.3s to find all symbols... I'm very surprising to find out that postgresql does not implement loose index scan.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to janes, the final solution would be

```
with symbol_set as (
    WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
       (SELECT symbol FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand ORDER BY symbol LIMIT 1)  -- parentheses required
       UNION ALL
       SELECT (SELECT symbol FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand WHERE symbol > t.symbol ORDER BY symbol LIMIT 1)
       FROM t
       WHERE t.symbol IS NOT NULL
       )
    SELECT symbol FROM t WHERE symbol IS NOT NULL
)
 SELECT * FROM symbol_set as db2 left join lateral 
   (select "timestamp" from db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand as db3 where db2.symbol=db3.symbol order by db3."timestamp" desc limit 1) as db4 on true;
```

it took 70ms in total compared with previously 10+s

Comment: Did you look at this post? https://blog.timescale.com/blog/how-we-made-distinct-queries-up-to-8000x-faster-on-postgresql/ I think you can use a distinct query to do this more simply...

Comment: `select distinct(symbol) FROM db_009a005a_df_downloaded_grand;` this takes more than 20s, while the approach i wrote above took 0.1s...

Comment: Hmm... interesting. I'm a bit surprised, are you on a recent version of Timescale? It should be doing basically the same thing under the hood. But if you're happy with the above then all's good.

Comment: yea... should be quite a recent one, i used timescale/timescaledb-ha:pg13-latest from 2-3 months ago.